# How to add or push data to local JSON file using javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm reading JSON file and delete the element after exact match. I want to push the remaining data to the JSON file after delete.

```
readJsonFile("./objects.json", function(jsonData){
  let parsedData = jsonData; // Parsed JSON data
    for (let i=0; i <= parsedData.data.length - 1; i++) {
      if (parsedData.data[i].id == did) {
         console.log('match record-->',parsedData.data[i].id);
         console.log('deleted record-->',did);
         if (delete parsedData.data.splice(i,1)) {
              // here I want to push the data to JSON file after delete
         }
      }
    }
});
```

Below is the the readJsonFile function

```
function readJsonFile(file, callback) {
  let jsonData;
  $.getJSON(file)
  .done(function (data) {
    jsonData = data;
    callback(jsonData);
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to send it back to server and write it to file there

Comment: You need a server (for example nodejs) to modify a file. It's easier to save all data to file instead of modifying part of it.

Comment: @charlietfl Sure. But I'm trying to do it without server.

Comment: Then all you can do is create a download as mentioned in answer below

Comment: @MortezaZiaeemehr I already done with the nodejs. But looking for without server .

Comment: @charlietfl That I already did to generate `backup.json` for the backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your JSON file local into **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** for example. You could use this as following:

To store the array (or object):

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(array));
```

To get the array (or object):

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || '[]');
```

**Example**

```
var array =
[
    {
        user: {icon: 'f007'},
        home: {icon: 'f015'},
        folder: {icon: 'f07c'}
    }
];

localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(array));

function readJsonFile(jsonData, callback)
{
    callback(jsonData);
}

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || '[]');

readJsonFile(data, function(data)
{
    console.log(data[0].home.icon); // f015
});
```

If you have an `Uncaught SecurityError` then read **[this site](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)**.

Comment: will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from this using jQuery, this is in the browser.

The browser can't write to the local file system, so you can't directly edit the file.

You could do something like (untested):

```
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(parsedData)], {type: 'application/json'});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {download: 'new.json', href: url});
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

to try and force the page to download the new JSON data.

Comment: That's all you can do. You can't write to the file system from the browser.